# Transcoding with ffmpeg libfaac reduces the audio duration

Tags: ffmpeg, transcode, libfaac

I have to transcode  a mpegts file: input.ts(H.264 and AAC)
So I use the following command line: 
`ffmpeg -y -i input.ts -acodec libfaac -vcodec copy out.ts`
But I find that the duration of output.ts's audio is shorter than that of the input.ts!

If I do the following iterations, the output's audio will be shorter and shorter.

```
ffmpeg -y -i out.ts -acodec libfaac -vcodec copy out-iter1.ts
ffmpeg -y -i out-iter1.ts -acodec libfaac -vcodec copy out-iter2.ts
ffmpeg -y -i out-iter2.ts -acodec libfaac -vcodec copy out-iter3.ts
ffmpeg -y -i out-iter3.ts -acodec libfaac -vcodec copy out-iter4.ts
ffmpeg -y -i out-iter4.ts -acodec libfaac -vcodec copy out-iter5.ts
```

My ffmpeg's version is 0.6.6. libfaac's version is 1.28.

input.ts's audio duration is 10.432 seconds. out-iter5.ts's audio duration is 10.56 seconds

And I have also tried ffmpeg with version 0.11.
And it makes the audio longer than the original input.

So my **question** is: **how to make sure the output's audio duration is same as the input's audio.
Since libfaac will make the audio shorter, how can I compensate for it?**
(For some reason I can't use -acodec copy directly.) Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you not use `-acodec copy` because of technical problems, or is there some other reason?  I ask because that's generally the best way to preserve the audio unchanged.

Comment: The resulting ts files are used for Apple's Http Live Streaming. If I directly use -acodec copy, some of those ts files' audio and video are out of sync. But if I use ffmpeg to do a transcoding, everything is okay, except that the audio's duration is shorter.

Comment: Now I modified the ffmpeg.c file. I've bypassed the av_decode_audio3 and the encode auido function, and copy the input packet's data to the output packet. Now the audio's duration is unchanged. But I hope to know why the video without a transcoding does not work well in Apple's Http Live Streaming. Is it the ts's header's problem? Thanks!